# Want new directory while extracting archive file using 7zip

Tags: archiving, 7-zip

I Have Some files and Directories in archive directory

- Archive

  - File_1
  - File_2
  - Directory_1
  - Directory_2

I want to create zip file of archive directory. But I do not want name `archive` zip Instead I want extra directory only at extracting time. Those are as follow.

- Main_Directory

  - First_Dir

    - File_1
    - File_2
    - Directory_1
    - Directory_2
      How can i achieve, This Using 7zip commands.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this page: http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/output_dir.htm

All you should need to do is specify the `-o` option & then a location and directory name, so the command would look like this:

`7z x (archive file) -o (unzip location)\Directory`

HTH

Comment: But this is extraction command i want it while creating archive. Is it possible ?

Comment: as specified in Help of this command "This switch can be used only with extraction commands".

Comment: Yeah, you can't actually create a directory that doesn't exist when you go to archive something.  You would have to create that directory structure prior to creating the archive.  At that point, you can extract the structure as it is without the requirement for the -o switch.

Comment: Okay I will create directory structure and then will archive it. Thank you for your help

Comment: @DigviJayPatil Did you manage to get this sorted in the end?  If you did, please mark the answer as accepted :)  Thanks